# How can I keep track of key presses on receiver end during a running voice call?

Tags: android

I want my Android application to make a voice call to a person and play one audio file when that person receives the call. This audio file instructs the person on receiver end to enter some numbers. This is just like a service provider call, which gives instructions to us and we follow them.

How can I keep track of keys the person is pressing during this call?

I need this, because, the numeric input given by the person will do something on application side. I also don't know whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

> my application will make a voice call to a person and play one audio file when that person receives the call

That is not supported by Android. You have no access to the in-call audio stream. The best you can do is play your audio file while the call is on, and *if* the device is in speakerphone mode, I think the other party will hear what you are playing.

> How can I keep track of keys the person is pressing during this call?

Most likely, you don't. It's conceivable that the speakerphone trick works in reverse (you pick up on the microphone what is coming in over the speaker), but then you will need to do all the audio processing to determine DTMF tones.

I strongly encourage you to use real solutions for IVR, whether they be hosted ones like [Voxeo](http://www.voxeo.com/) or something you create yourself using Asterisk on a Linux box. IVR is not what Android is designed for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't want to use some third party solution.
You suggested me to **Use Asterisk on Linux box** - Can you please explain this option. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go through this link.